# How do I clear Neovim window after exiting Neovim on Window 10

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows

On Linux, when I exit Neovim, the content in the Neovim window is cleared. But on Windows 10, when I exit Neovim, the content is still shown and is not cleared, leaving a lot of empty space (see image below). By the way, I am using Neovim inside [cmder](http://cmder.net/).

I have searched with Goolgle, but can not find useful info. A related question is post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60499/how-to-set-the-bash-display-to-not-show-the-vim-text-after-exit), but it is for Linux.

So how to clear the content of Neovim when I exit on Windows 10?

[image]

Comment: I don't have enough experience with Windows to answer, but it might be useful to detail how you are using nvim on Windows 10: via the powershell console, via the WSL, via cygwin or a similar tool, or via something else. I think that would help other people to answer your question.

Comment: This depends on your terminal. What terminal are you using? In Vim you can configure it using the terminal options `t_...`, not sure if this works on Windows cmd. Unfortunately, neovim removed all those special terminal options `t_<...>`, so cannot say it for neovim.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I am using neovim inside cmder. I have updated this info.

Answer (score 1):

After more search about related issues. I have finally found a solution which works for Cmder. Open Cmder settings and go to `Startup -> Environment`, add the following settings:

```
set TERM=xterm-256color
```

[image]

Restart Cmder and the issue should disappear.

Comment: Future readers be warned: this type of explicit setting of `TERM` only works if the terminal emulator is, in fact, emulating xterm-256color

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me in PowerShell Core by adding

```
$env:TERM='xterm-256color'
```

to `$PROFILE`.